# Diference between API calls dononreferencedcredit and direct payment

Tags: php, paypal

Im new in PayPal and I just want to ask, what is functional diference between API calls dononreferencedcredit and direct payment?
I understand it, that both send money to credit card, is it correct?

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to send money from my paypal account to credit/debit card or bank account of someone else using Paypal payments Standard? Or is it possible using PRO version? Exists any API or anything else for it?

Answer (score 3):

DoDirectPayment takes money from a card and DoNonReferenceCredit issues a credit to a card.

In most cases you'd be more interested in DoDirectPayment and RefundTransaction, as the RefundTransaction API call will refund whatever type of transaction, charged via whichever funding source (be it card, bank, PayPal balance, et cetera).

DoNonReferencedCredit would only apply for a limited set of use cases; e.g. if you wish to disburse funds directly to someone's credit card.  However, even this can already be handled by the MassPay API call where MassPay disburses it to the PayPal balance of the receiver, and the receiver can do with these funds as they please.

Comment: I need to disburse variouse amount of funds to credit card. So as you wrote, you would prefere DoNonReferencedCredit, becouse i don`t need to know transaction ID. Is it right? And MassPay is only between 2 or more paypal accounts, isn`t it?

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that `dononreferencedcredit`issues credit to a card, while it's not being referenced in the original transaction. See [this page](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro) for more information.

Comment: Yes thats what i want... not to be referenced to original transaction. So if I understand it right, for me is better DoNonReferencedCredit.

Answer (score 0):

DoNonReferencedCredit is definitely the way to go if you do not want or do not have a reference to the original transaction. PayPal accounts do not allow NonReferenceCredits by default, you will have to contact business support to have this option enabled on your account.

You will receive the following error if NonReferenceCredits are not enabled on your account.

"Invalid merchant information: 10002-You do not have permissions to make this API call"

Comment: Yes I got failure response, but this one 10764- This transaction cannot be processed at this time. Please try again later. Is it because I didn`t contact support?

Comment: If you continue to receive the error, I would suggest that you contact support for assistance. You can file a support ticket at www.paypal.com/mts.